# Use core data to send email with string

Tags: string, email, core-data

I have set up a core data model and I would like the ability to be able to tap on an entry and have an blank email pop up with the core data contents included. here is my code for saving the data-

```
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSNumber *timetickNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeTick];
NSString *versionString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minutes of %@", self.versionTextField.text];
[newDevice setValue:timetickNumber forKey:@"name"];
[newDevice setValue:versionString forKey:@"version"];
[newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you looking for? Have you tried to send email, and if so, what happened? Have you tried to use `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have a view controller with the MFMailComposeViewController. I also have the Message UI framework added to my project. I want to know how to have it so that I can click on a core data entry and it will open the view controller with the data in string format.

Answer (score 0):

You can't click (or tap) on a Core Data object, because they do not have any UI and do not respond to UI events. The general flow you want is probably something like:

1. Figure out what UI element should trigger the email action-- a button, or a table row, or whatever UI element you're using.
2. In the handler method for taps on that element, create the `MFMailComposeViewController`. Where this happens depends on what UI element you're using. If your UI element is a button, this happens in whatever method your button calls when tapped. If the UI element is a table row, you probably want to use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view's delegate.
3. In that same method, get a reference to the managed object you want to send. If you fetched it (or created it) earlier, you might already have an instance var that points to it. If not, you may need to fetch it here.
4. Before displaying the `MFMailComposeViewController`, configure either the message body (via `setMessageBody:isHTML:`) or the attachment (via `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`) to contain the data from your managed object's data
5. Display the mail compose view to the user.

Comment: I have a table view controller to display the core data. Could you tell me where I would create the MFMailComposeViewController? Also, how can I tell if I have the instance variable for step 3?

Comment: Step 2 describes where to create the mail compose view. You have an instance variable in step 3 if you created one and assigned a value to it, otherwise you do not.

Comment: `MFMailComposeViewController` is pretty well documented, which part do you not understand?